# When doing integration by parts/tabular integration and you do a u-sub can you only resub the variable at the end?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I was just wondering if during tabular integration (DI method)/ibp you do a substitution during one of the steps can you carry the substitution until the end and only change the variable back at the end?

i.e. would this be valid:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ln(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{t e^t}{e^{2t}+1}\,dt\\
t=ln(x)\\e^t dt=dx$$

Let $$D = t,1,0$$ for the first 3 rows
$$
I\\
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{e^t}{e^{2t}+1}\,dt\\z=e^t\\dz=e^tdt\\ \ \\
\int\frac{dz}{z^2+1}= \arctan(z)$$

Would it be valid at this point if we went and integrated wrt to z again?

i.e.

$$t\arctan(z)-\int{\arctan(z)}dz\\=t\arctan(e^t)-e^t\arctan(e^t)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(e^{2t}+1)\\=\ln(x)\arctan(x)+x\arctan(x)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)$$

or would you have to integrate it after you resubstitute the original variable like this:
$$t\arctan(e^t)-\int\arctan(e^t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, yes, you can always use a substitution to evaluate an integral regardless of where that integral appears, but you need to be careful about preserving the relationships across the various substitutions.

If your substitution is such that $\int f(t) dt = \int g(z) dz$, there's nothing stopping you from evaluating $\int g(z) dz$ without going back to $t$ until you reach a point where you need to do so.

In fact, your last line would be *incorrect* - you cannot replace $z$ with $e^t$ inside an integral sign unless you also replace $dz$ with $\frac{dz}{dt} dt$, which would just give you an integral that you'd probably need to go back and substitute $z$ into again in order to solve.